# Trigger popup on publish post

Tags: plugins

I want to trigger a popup whenever a post is published. The popup is simple, just notifying the user that the post has been published with a link of the post (optional).

I am open to explore options via custom coding or using plugins, anything that works.

Comment: You should provide some examples of things you've tried to do this yourself first, and then ask the community for help troubleshooting.

Comment: You can either do this on page load, or whilst the user is browsing the site either by polling or web sockets (but that seems a waste of effort unless you're publishing very frequently), or web push notifications (although I think they aren't real push notifications and actually poll under the covers)